# Using a recursive method to remove duplicates from collection

Tags: java, recursion, collections

I'm trying to write a code consisting of a generic method which takes in a collection of objects and modifies it as the following:
1)if there's only 1 instance of that object, leave it there;
2)if there's more than one, remove all of them and place null **once** instead.

Example:

```
[1,2,2] -> [1,null]
["dog","cat","cat","fish"] -> ["dog",null,"fish"]
```

The method has to be recursive.
I tried my best with this:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    public class Sequence 
    {
        public static <T> T cleanSequence(Collection<T> 
    collectionElements)
        {   
            Collection finalCollection = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<T> collectionArrayList = new ArrayList<> 
   (collectionElements);
            T firstObject = collectionArrayList.get(0);
            int size = collectionArrayList.size();
    if (size == 1)  
    {
        finalCollection.add(firstObject);
        collectionElements = finalCollection;
        return firstObject;
    }
    else if (size == 2)
    {
        if (firstObject.equals(collectionArrayList.get(1)))
        {
            finalCollection.add(null);
            collectionElements = finalCollection;
            return null;
        }
        else 
        {
            finalCollection.add(firstObject);
            collectionElements = finalCollection;
            collectionArrayList.remove(firstObject);
            finalCollection.add(cleanSequence(collectionArrayList));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (firstObject.equals(collectionArrayList.get(1)))
        {
            finalCollection.add(null);
            collectionArrayList.remove(firstObject);
            finalCollection.add(cleanSequence(collectionArrayList));
        }
        else
            finalCollection.add(firstObject);
            collectionArrayList.remove(firstObject);
            finalCollection.add(cleanSequence(collectionArrayList));
        }
    collectionElements = finalCollection;
    return null;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrList.add(1);  arrList.add(1); arrList.add(2);
    cleanSequence(arrList);
    System.out.println(arrList);
}
```

}

Result:

```
[null, 2]  //expected result
[1,1,2]    //actual result
```

I can't see where's the mistake(s), do you guys/girls have any idea?Thank you.

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Posted code is not valid Java.

Comment: [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: It runs fine in my Eclipse, perhaps I copypasted it wrong here.

Comment: What should the result of processing `[1,2,1,3,1]` be, and why?

Comment: I tried to copy it again, hope it works now. As of the new question: [1,2,1,3,1] because they're not in sequence.